Why does MAXX not add the row context to filter context without CALCULATE?
MAXX(CUSTOMER, SUMX(SALES,SALES[AMT]+0))

The above doesn't add customer into the folder context when performing the SUMX
Where as the following does:
MAXX(CUSTOMER, CALCULATE(SUMX(SALES,SALES[AMT]+0)))

Why does MAXX not add the row context to filter context without CALCULATE?

Calculate creates a context transition in this case.
https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-context-transition/

When it evaluated at each row without calculate why does it consider all rows?

Because no filter context is provided which is what calculate does (convert the row to a filter context)

Ok so otherwise it behaves like how calculated column would do. Difficult to grasp this concept. So you mean that MAXX is a iterator and when it goes row by row it behaves like a calculated column and hence we need CALCULATE to perform the context transition - that is add row to filter context.

Yes, that is correct
